# How to avoid dividing by zero error?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-optimization

I'm using MATLAB to calculate magnitude and phase of an image.  I use the following formula to get the phase angle:

```
Phase_Angle = tan^-1(Y_Magnitude/X_Magnitude)
```

So if the X_Magnitude matrix contains zero values will result **NaN** 
No body will like that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I very much doubt that `tan^-1(...)` is valid MATLAB code. You probably mean `atan(...)`.

If instead you use [`atan2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html), you'll get the actual phase, as opposed to the phase modulo π. Plus you don't have to worry about division by zero:

```
Phase_Angle = atan2(Y_Magnitude, X_Magnitude);
```

Comment: No its not valid in MATLAB, I mentioned the equation formula but I was using atan(...).
anyway atan2 solve my problem.. thank you very much :)